# I trying to launch instance by configure test event - json format by throwing parameter values but it doesn't run without errors

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, boto3

Could anyone please clear this issue or correct this code.

1. Configure Test Event:
   [Configure Test Event:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmfuq.png)

lambda Function Code:

```
 import boto3
    import json
     
    AMI = 'AMI'
    INSTANCE_TYPE = 'INSTANCE_TYPE'
    KEY_NAME = 'KEY_NAME'
    REGION = 'REGION'
    SUBNET_ID = 'SUBNET_ID'
    SECURITYGROUP_ID = 'SECURITYGROUP_ID'
     
     
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
     
     
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
     
        instance = ec2.run_instances(
            ImageId=AMI,
            InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
            KeyName=KEY_NAME,
            MaxCount=1,
            MinCount=1
        )
      
        
        print ("New instance created:")
        instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
        print (instance_id)
     
        return instance_id
```

I Get Error Like This

```
"errorMessage": "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \"https://ec2.REGION.amazonaws.com/\"",
  "errorType": "EndpointConnectionError",
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi , I have added the error link on the question. please review and advise

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screenshot, but as text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `REGION` is just a string `"REGION"` because its outside `lambda_handler`. It should be:

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):

        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=event['REGION'])     
     
        instance = ec2.run_instances(
            ImageId=event['AMI'],
            InstanceType=event['INSTANCE_TYPE'],
            KeyName=event['KEY_NAME'],
            MaxCount=1,
            MinCount=1
        )
```

Comment: Now i see error like this @Marcin

{
  "errorMessage": "'dict' object is not callable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=event('REGION'))\n"
  ]
}

Comment: @PraveenSivakumar Anwser updated.